# Copy from hex character array to char * type

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a global hex character array like this :

```
static char data[9] =  {0x01, 0xF2, 0x01, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x11};
```

I want to copy this buffer to my character array passed from main()

```
void getBuffer (char *buffer)
{
   // HOW TO COPY from 'data' to 'buffer'
}

int main()

{

   char *out = new char[9];
   getBuffer (out);

}
```

Tried with memcpy, strcpy but didnt work. Looks like i have to format to string somehow for copying ?? 
I am doing this in standard C++ so can use `std::string` related features as well.

Comment: What are you expecting the character array to contain?

Comment: I would be very surprised if `memcpy` did not work. Please show us the call to `memcpy` you used.

Comment: What symptoms do you see that make you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Prove to us that memcpy doesn't work.  You're probably just using it wrong.

Comment: Oh.  Perhaps you think that your "hex" character array is supposed to contain the collection of printable character "0x01", "0xF2" (each contains 4 character),...  What you have is character code 0x01, character code 0xF2...  None of which actually convert to printable characters.  Is this where your issue lies?

Comment: "Hex" isn't some special kind of number or character, it's just a different way of *writing* numbers. Your array is equivalent to `{1, 242, 1, 2, 5, 255, 254, 0, 17};`.

Comment: @user1395887 _'Looks like i have to format to string'_ Looks a bit like an XY-problem, can you elaborate in your question what you finally want to achieve please?

Comment: You have the value 0xFF in a `char` array.  The `char` type can be signed or unsigned or `char`.  Did you want signed or unsigned?  The usual type should be `uint8_t` or on many machines, `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` work fine, use this implementation.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned char data[9] = {0x01, 0xF2, 0x01, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x11};

void    getBuffer(unsigned char *buffer)
{
    memcpy(buffer, data, sizeof(data));
}

int     main(int argc, char const** argv)
{
    unsigned char   *out = new unsigned char[sizeof(data)];
    unsigned int    i = 0;

    getBuffer(out);
    while (i < sizeof(data))
    {
        printf("0x%x|", out[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    return (0);
}
```

if you have `0xf2` in your array then it's an `unsigned char array`.

Good luck :)

Comment: I think your answer misses some points. But well, we're both a bit speculative because the OP's question isn't that clear about the actual requirements.

Comment: `memcpy(buffer, data, sizeof(data));` And in which way is this superior for going to get C++ standard compliant vs `std::copy(data, data + sizeof(data),buffer);` as I have stated in 1st place?

Comment: @QuentinPerez Sorry, I just had to downvote to outweigh, the imprudent upvote for your answer. It's not really wrong, but no way better. As mentioned, at least the problem is the _'poor'_ question actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::copy(data, data + sizeof(data),buffer);
```

should work fine for what you're currently showing.

> Tried with memcpy, strcpy but didnt work. Looks like i have to format to string somehow for copying ?? I am doing this in cpp so can use string related functionalities as well.

I think the crucial thing you say to detect your actual needs is you mention `'i have to format to string somehow'`. Yes you'll need to do some formatting to see *'hex'* values appearing as a simple text string.

Here are some alternatives, how to do such formatting right

```
void getBuffer(std::ostream& buffer) {
    buffer << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0');
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
       if(i) {
           buffer << ", ";
       }
       buffer << "0x" << (unsigned int)data[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    getBuffer (std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

An alternative is to get a `std::string` returned from the `getBuffer()` function

```
void getBuffer(std::string& buffer) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss<< hex << setw(2) << setfill('0');
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(data); ++i) {
       if(i) {
           oss << ", ";
       }
       oss << "0x" << (unsigned int)data[i];
    }
    buffer = oss.str();
}

int main() {
    std::string out;
    getBuffer (out);
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

Or at least as I'd prefer it, is to have a function that does this independently from a global static data variable, and choose a more comprehensive naming

```
std::string getHexBytesFormat(const char* data, size_t size) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss<< hex << setw(2) << setfill('0');
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
       if(i) {
           oss << ", ";
       }
       oss << "0x" << (unsigned int)data[i];
    }
    return oss.str();
}

static char data[9] =  {0x01, 0xF2, 0x01, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x11};

int main() {
    std::cout << getHexBytesFormat(data,sizeof(data)) << std::endl;
}
```

The whole thing about formatting, and manipulating output (and input) streams is explained in detail in [this part of the standard documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: The `std::copy` line at the top is wrong because it uses `sizeof`.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg What's wrong about using `sizeof()` for a globally accessible static array like `static char data[9];` please? Can you elaborate about this? Note I said _'should work fine for what you're currently showing.'_

Comment: My mistake, I was a bit hasty in reading the code and only saw the dynamically allocated array.